# Map Preview google maps api V2

Tags: android, api, maps

I'm developing an andoid app that use the google maps api V2. I need to show to the user a little preview of the map like there is in Google Maps App or Google Now (See the screen)

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMWjh.png)

[Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxCAI.png)

There is any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lite mode map`:

> A lite mode map is a bitmap image of a map at a specified location and zoom level. Lite mode supports all of the map types (normal, hybrid, satellite, terrain) and a subset of the functionality supplied by the full API. Lite mode is useful when you want to provide a number of maps in a stream, or a map that is too small to support meaningful interaction.

For detail, go through the doc [Google Maps Android API v2 Lite Mode map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite)

Hope this help!

Comment: Absolutely, you can check this post and my answer [Google Maps Lite Mode causes jank in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612782/google-maps-lite-mode-causes-jank-in-recyclerview/28692318#28692318)

Comment: excuse me but is not easier to use the old static map? Specially in a listview? I just started programming android..

Comment: Of course you can still use static map, but lite map is the replacement and improved

Comment: @diegocom yes its easy to use. but unfortunately static map api is no longer free.